# Selenium IDE assert XML answer

Tags: xml, selenium, firefox-addon, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I'm looking for a way to assert Text of an XML result.
I'm using it for test some webservices.

The XML looks like this:

```
<ProductsResult>
   <Total>12679</Total>
   <Duration>4099</Duration>
   <Hits>
      <Product>
         <ProductNumber>ABC</ProductNumber>
      </Product>
   </Hits>
   <HitsByProductNumber>
      <Product>
         <ProductNumber>ABC</ProductNumber>
      </Product>
   </HitsByProductNumber>
</ProductsResult>
```

Now i need to check the ProductNumber Tag, but just in the "Hits" tag.
To check all ProductNumber tags is no problem.
This I do in this way:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>clickAndWait</td>
               <td>css=input.button</td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>assertXpathCount</td>
               <td>//*[name() = 'ProductNumber' and text() = 'ABC']</td>
               <td>1</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How to check "Product" just in the "Hits" tag ;-)

Comment: We found the solution. It was easy... //*[name() = 'Hits']/*[name() = 'Product'] :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer.

It was quite easy.

I still use the assertXpathCount and in the Target I use:

```
//*[name() = 'Hits']/*[name() = 'Product']
```

Now I can access all Products in the Hits Tag.